# Can you create dynamic power query formulas in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, string, powerquery, double-quotes

I used the macro recorder in Excel to import a table from a PDF into the Power Query editor, and then to export the transformed table to excel.

I want to reuse this code for other similar PDF tables that are identical in structure.

The issue is that the "Value Balance" column will have a different date in each PDF table. I would like to use a dynamic variable to handle the updated date. The concatenation I used with the variable "RefDate" in the below code does not work:

Sub Macro1()

```
RefDate = "05-05-22"

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table001 (Page 1)", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""C:\Users\MyPDF.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.3""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table001 = Source{[Id=""Table001""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Table001, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Ac" & _
    "count Code"", type text}, {""Ccy"", type text}, {""Book Balance"", type number}, {""Value Balance#(lf)"" & RefDate, type number}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
```

End Sub

How can I create a dynamic string in this type of nested code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in your post how the variable name is green. That is a visual indicator that it is inside the string. You have to break the string and concatenate the variable. Compare the following examples:

```vb
MyString = "The value is MyVar."

MyString = "The value is " & MyVar & "."
```

Comment: You may need to convert the PDF file to a text file, and then import data from a text file, and then...you will have much more control over the data import process. Are you interested in this kind of solution?

Comment: The string in the code I submitted is a little more complex than I am familiar with, how would you break up that particular string?

Comment: @Adam I'm not really sure what your table looks like but you need to change `{""Value Balance#(lf)"" & RefDate, type number}` to look more like `{""" & Something & RefDate & """, type number}`. Triple quotes so that the string is closed but also adds an actual " mark. You can also wrap `RefDate` inside a `Format` function so that you can control how it is transformed into the String. Like `Format(RefDate, "yyyy-MM-dd")` to make sure it gets represented in that form.

Comment: @Toddleson, after some playing around in the codechef.com compiler, I was able to identify the start and end of the parent string. You were right to use triple quotes, as the double quotes within the curly brackets needed to appear in the parent string:

`"  = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Account Code"", type text}, {""Ccy"", type text}, {""Book Balance"", type number}, {" & """Value Balance#(lf)" & RefDate & """, type number}})"`

Comment: So for the final solution, I had to do a single quote right after the curly bracket to break up the parent string, and then concatenate a string that began with double quotes, then the variable, and then another pair of double quotes:

`" PARENT STRING {" & """Value Balance#(lf)" & RefDate & """, type number}})"`

Or: `"PARENT STRING" & """Nested String" & Variable & """ PARENT STRING"`